# json syntax error in header

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting SyntaxError:JSON.parse in the ajax error function and when trying to validate via json validator, it says that the header was undefined and was expecting {,[ Is my header code incorrect? Many thanks

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header("Pragma: no-cache" );
header("Content-type: application/json");
$json = "";
$json .= "{\n";
$json .=  "\"company\": \"".$company."\",\n";
$json .=  "\"box\": \"".$box."\",\n";
$json .=  "\"dept\": \"".$dept."\",\n";
$json .=  "\"submit\": \"".$submit."\",\n";
$json .=  "\"service\": \"".$service."\",\n";
$json .=  "\"address\": \"".$address."\",\n";
$json .=  "\"authorised\": \"".$authorised."\"\n";
$json .= "}\n";
echo $json;
```

Comment: Show us the actual JSON output, please.

Comment: @matt there is no output. firebug is only showing html in response. Thanks

Comment: @bollo - that sounds like you are fetching the wrong URL

Comment: And has nobody heard of interpolation? Or heredoc?

Comment: @quentin url is correct. After the suggestion by Dhruv, the error has gone, but I am still not seeing JSON in firebug to show the data is being returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not try to write your own json. JSON easily becomes invalid if it has unescaped quotes,invalid characters etc.

Better store everything in php array and then use PHPs inbuilt

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to create the json .

see example here :  http://codepad.org/Iaa0zx9J

```
<?php

$dataArr = array(
"company" => "abc corp",
"dept" => "finance",
"submit" => "100"
);

$myJsonString = json_encode($dataArr);
echo $myJsonString ;

?>
```

Comment: how would that work for variables? for example, in my code I would need to include variables in the return. Would they just be used like thus: "company" => ".$company.", thanks